# Метаданные MP3

Tags: java, mp3, jlayer

Сколько бит/байт занимают метаданные в MP3 или как это можно узнать с помощью библиотеки JLayer на Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последние 128 байт файла mp3 содержат метаданные. Можете написать программу которая считывает их. Структура:

| Song title | 30 characters |
| --- | --- |
| Artist | 30 characters |
| Album | 30 characters |
| Year | 4 characters |
| Comment | 30 characters |
| Genre | 1 byte |

Но это для ID3v1,у ID3v2 структура сложнее.[Описание](http://www.fightingquaker.com/myid3/) можно посмотреть здесь.
Библиотека для чтения информации [здесь.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jd3lib/)

Comment: Я пользуюсь JLayer. Там есть метод, который возвращает их. Я просто хотел обрезать их с потока, чтобы склеить 2 файла в 1. Но тут какая-то другая загвоздка. Он не видит все данные 2го файла после их соединения и воспроизводит только первую часть