# Как узнать название песни из байтового потока загруженного по ссылке

Tags: java, input

Начальный параметр ссылка, в данном классе по этой ссылке я записываю на компьютер байтовый массив. Как из данного массива узнать название файла (в данном случае песни)

```
private URL urls;
private File musicDirectory;
private String name;   

public MyThread(String str, File musicDirectory) {
    try {
        this.urls = new URL(str);
        this.musicDirectory = musicDirectory;
        this.name = new File(urls.getFile()).getName();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

 File file = new File(musicDirectory, name);

        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                urls.openStream())) {
            try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(file))) {
                URLConnection urlcon = urls.openConnection();
                int sizeUrlcon = urlcon.getContentLength();

                int count;
                int size = 0;
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                while ((count = bis.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                    bos.write(data, 0, count);
                    size = size + count;
                }
                System.out
                        .printf("Finish download  %s size %d urlcon.getContentLength() %d%n",
                                name, size, sizeUrlcon);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считывание метаданных можно осуществить с помощью библиотеки JLayer, например. Ещё стоит почитать про аналогичный ответ на [so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12110/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-mp3).

Comment: надо узнать название песни из байткода

Comment: вопрос про байткод, в своем коде я узнаю название по ссылке, мне этого не достаточно)

Comment: Так выражайтесь конкретно. Вам нужно прочитать тег из аудио файла?

Comment: да, надо узнать тег - название песни

Comment: @makson, обновил ответ